# Using 1N5822 (40v 3A) schottky instead of 1N5819 (40v, 1A)

Tags: schottky

Is it okay to substitute 1A 40V Schottky with 40V 3A version of it and what can go wrong with that setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have nearly the same V<sub>F</sub> and R<sub>th-JA</sub> at the same conditions. But 5822 has higher leakage current level.

So the answer is: It depends on usage and required electrical performance.

If the diode is a part of an SMPS (e.g. buck converter), or it's used to protect semiconductors against spikes (e.g. placing across the coil of a relay), or simply it's used just for a reverse polarity protection purpose then yes, you can safely use 5822 in place of a 5819.

But if it's used in a power-OR of a circuit including backup battery then the leakage current may be a problem.

The size should be considered as well since 5822 is bigger. It also requires bigger holes (1.5mm dia) for proper mounting and soldering.